# Specular Mapping in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I am a new bid in the world of OpenGL ES 2.0. I am trying to implement specular mapping using OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS platform. As per my knowledge,in specular mapping we extract the value for the specular component of light from specular map texture. What i am doing in vertex shader is as follows:

```
vec3 N = NormalMatrix * Normal;
vec3 L = normalize(LightPosition);
vec3 E = normalize(EyePosition);
vec3 H = normalize(L + E);
vec4 Specular=(texture2D(sampler_spec, TextureCoordIn)).rgba;

float df = max(0.0, dot(N, L));
float sf = max(0.0, dot(N, H));
sf = pow(sf, Specular.a);

vec3 color = AmbientMaterial + df * DiffuseMaterial + sf * Specular.rgb * SpecularMaterial;

DestinationColor = vec4(color, 1);  `
```

But I can't see any specular effect in my game. I don't know where i am going wrong. Please give your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Well your computations look quite reasonable. The problem is, you're doing per-vertex lighting. This means the lighting is computed per vertex (as you're doing it in the vertex shader) and interpolated accross the triangles. Therefore your lighting quality highly depends on the tessellation quality of your mesh.

If you have rather large triangles, such high frequency effects like specular highlights won't really show. Especially when using textures. Keep in mind that the reason for using textures is to provide surface detail at a sub-triangle level, but at the moment you're reading the texture per vertex, so the specular could just be a vertex attribute.

So the first step would be to move the lighting computations into the fragment shader. In the vertex shader you just compute `N`, `L` and `E` (don't forget to normalize) and put them out as varyings. In the fragment shader you do the rest of the computation, based on the interpolated `N`, `L` and `E` (don't forget to renormalize again).

If all these concepts of varyings and per-fragment lighting are a bit high-fetched at the moment, you should delve a little deeper into the basics of shaders and look for tutorials on simple per-fragment lighting shaders. These can then easily adapted for things like specular mapping or bump mapping, ...

Comment: Hi Christian Rau,  according to your reply I shifted my lighting calculations in the fragment shader. One more thing that i want to ask from u regarding bump mapping. I also want to implement bump map. I studied a bit about bump mapping and most of the things are clear. I am using OBJs for rendering the geometry. I am getting difficulty in finding the per vertex tangents that are required for bump mapping. U seem to have good professional knowledge, so please give your valuable suggestions for finding per vertex tangents required in bump mapping.....

Comment: @hurricane That would surely be worth another question, but first you could look [here](http://www.terathon.com/code/tangent.html) and [here](http://fabiensanglard.net/bumpMapping/index.php) for the formulas. The idea is to compute the tangent and bitangent for each triangle (as they are constant per triangle and depend on the texture coordinates of the triangle's vertices) and then average the tangents of all adjacent triangles for each vertex.

Comment: @hurricane So does the specular mapping work correctly now? If yes, up-voting and accepting is always appreciated. If not, feel free to update your question or write a comment on it.

Comment: As you said specular mapping effect also depends upon the size of triangles, i am yet to try the code for geometry with smaller traingles and i would surely appreciate your advice if it worked with up-voting.....:)

Comment: @hurricane No! I said effects like specular lighting or spot lights highly depend on the tessellation quality **if done in the vertex shader**. The advantage of per-fragment lighting computations is that lighting is more independent of the tessellation quality of the mesh, that's why I suggested it. So your specular mapping should actually work now (if you have a reasonable specualr map, of course). Look for the differences between [Gouraud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) and [Phong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading) shading.

Comment: So what according to you is reasonable specular map?

Comment: @hurricane Don't know, one that works? Don't you have one to test?

Comment: Yes i do have a sample specular map but i am not sure that its perfect or not. I do definately try some other specular maps also....One thing to confirm, in specular mapping which texture is binded on the geometry specular texture or diffuse texture?

Comment: @hurricane Huh? I don't understand your last question. Both the specular and the diffuse texture are usually object specific, as they specify the reflective properties of the object, if that was your question.

Comment: i tried the specular map and getting some results also......when the camera is moved shininess on the surface is seen for 2-3 seconds after that normal texture is visible with no shininess.Is it the case with specular map? Shouln't be the specular effect should remain until the camera is in that particular direction?